# Hooking into a Storyboard.Complete event with MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Basically, what I've got is a simple alert message setup. There is a view for the individual alerts with some data-binding to the VM for their text and color (green for success, red for error, etc.).

```
<Border Margin="0 0 0 20" Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor}" BorderBrush="#D4D4D4" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="DarkGray"/>
    </Border.Effect>
<Grid >
        <Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="268,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.48,0.727"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Message" 
           Foreground="White" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="13px"
           Text="{Binding Path=Message}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="-4.395,-0.038" Margin="7,13,0,25"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The goal is to have them be dismissed when you click the 'X' button, with a nice fade animation. I've got a storyboard in to handle the fading:

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

Now, what I wanted to do is then have Caliburn.Micro hook into the storyboard's `Completed` event with a method to dimiss the actual view (there is a bindable collection of these alerts in another view so that the alerts will stack and then be dismissed at the user's desire).

I tried something like this at first, thinking that it would work the same as any of my other bindings:

```
<Storyboard cal:Message.Attach="[Event Completed] = [Action DismissMessage($source, $eventArgs)]">
<!-- rest of the codez... -->
```

But got the following error:

```
Cannot attach type "ActionMessage" to type "Storyboard". Instances of type "ActionMessage" can only be attached to objects of type "FrameworkElement".
```

And this makes well enough sense I guess...but then what is the best way to handle something like this binding? My mind inevitably starts to wander to attempting some hacky solution like calling the viewmodel from the view's code-behind, but it seems like that violates MVVM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Basically, CMs implementation of actions works for elements based on FrameworkElement (for good reasons). There's a discussion on why what doesn't work (any why) here: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/250844 - have a read of that, it might give you some insight. As for a workaround, you might find yourself biting the bullet and putting some code in the views codebehind for this one. One idea could be to use the `EventAggregator` and provide an event for when the storyboard completes, then subscribe to this in the VM to dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've commented, an easier way out might be the aggregator.

When the `StoryBoard` completes, you can just fire an event via the aggregator (or a specific aggregator for dialogs even) and handle that in the VM to close the dialog

e.g. you will need something that provides the aggregator if you don't have one (not sure if you are using DI or not)

```
public static DialogEventAggregatorProvider  
{
    public static EventAggregator { get; set; } // Obviously instantiate this, I'll leave the code out for brevity
}
```

in your views codebehind:

```
public SomeView : UserControl
{
    private void StoryBoard_Completed(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogEventAggregatorProvider.EventAggregator.Publish(new CloseDialogMessage()); // Add some args or what have you if it helps identify what dialog to close, but try not to break MVVM ;)
    }
}
```

in the VM

```
public SomeViewModel : Screen, IHandle<CloseDialogMessage>
{
    public SomeViewModel() 
    {
        // Don't forget to subscribe or you'll be scratching your head
        DialogEventAggregatorProvider.EventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Handle(CloseDialogMessage message) 
    { 
        // if(message.HasSomeValue) Here you could check the type of message etc.
           TryClose();
    }
}
```

It's not that pretty, but as long as you keep the implementation generic you can get away without violating MVVM principles

Comment: I am very new to WPF dev so I'm not totally sure how to use event aggregators, but I'm assuming it's not too bad so I'll take a stab at it. Thanks for the thorough response, I'll report back!

Comment: It's part of Caliburn.Micro, just a publisher/subscriber model - you create an aggregator which mediates the communication between the subscribers and publishers. Subscribers need to call `Aggregator.Subscribe(subscriber)` and publishers use `Aggregator.Publish(message)`. The subscriber must implement the `IHandle<messageType>` interface, where `messageType` is the type of messages it will listen to (you can pass around any type you want as a message). The message handler will fire on all subscribers which are currently listening to a particular message type.

Comment: Awesome, this ended up working! I have some other things to work out as far as the details of the messageType but the event handling worked great. Good to see that CM has built in functionality to help with this. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked - there's usually a way, this is not quite as nice as being able to handle events on any type for action messages, but it at least keeps the MVVM stuff happy and everything decoupled

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to avoid view code behind is to use a `StoryboardCompletedTrigger` from Blend interactivity library :

First include right references in your xaml :

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/
xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Then add your interaction trigger to your view and set its action to `CallMethodAction`

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <ie:StoryboardCompletedTrigger Storyboard="{StaticResource MyStoryboard}">
    <ie:CallMethodAction MethodName="DismissMessage" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
  </ie:StoryboardCompletedTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could bind that event to a command using Marlon Grech Attached Command Behaviors library.

the library can be downloaded from here:
http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/

Comment: I tried to look through that but I'm not seeing exactly how it'll help...plus it's from more than 3 years ago and the author specifically says it's not very well tested, haha. Thanks for the suggestion though.